# Get locale id from time zone

Tags: javascript, date-fns

Is there any option to get locale id from time zone?

For example: for `Australia/Sydney` I want to get `en-AU`.

Comment: So for CET (Central European Time) you want to get  Albania, Andorra, Austria, Belgium, Bosnia and Herzegovina, Croatia, Czechia, Denmark (except Greenland and Faroe Islands), France (except overseas regions), Germany, Gibraltar, Hungary, Italy, Kosovo, Liechtenstein, Luxembourg, Malta, Monaco, Montenegro, Netherlands (except Caribbean island territories), North Macedonia, Norway, Poland, San Marino, Serbia, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain (except Canary Islands), Sweden, Switzerland or Vatican City?

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen I'm talking about tz database time zones (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). If I use "console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone)" I get "Europe/Warsaw". And based on that I would like to somehow get "pl".

Comment: @Pavel And there you have your answer. Make a mapping and you are home...

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen I was wondering if there is such mapping somewhere already :)